# Azure Graph Query in az graph query command

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-sql-database

```
Resources
| where type has "microsoft.compute/disks"
| extend diskState = tostring(properties.diskState)
| where managedBy == ""
or diskState == 'Attached'
or diskState == 'Unattached'
| project name, diskState,managedBy,resourceGroup, location, subscriptionId, properties.diskSizeGB, properties.timeCreated
```

How do I convert this KQL Query into a az graph query command?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. What have you tried?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: az graph query -q “Resources | where type =~ ‘microsoft.compute/disks’ | extend diskState = tostring(properties.diskState) | where managedBy == "" or diskState == 'Attached' or diskState == 'Unattached' | project name, diskState,managedBy,resourceGroup, location, subscriptionId, diskSize=properties.diskSizeGB, timeCreation=properties.timeCreated” --query ‘data[].{Disk_Name:name, Disk_State:diskState, Managed_By:managedBy, Resource_Group:resourceGroup, Location:location, Subscription_Id:subscriptionId, Disk_Size:diskSize, Time_of_Creation:timeCreation}’ -o tsv

I tried this out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm from the Microsoft for Founders Hub team. I was able to run this and it worked as intended:

```
az graph query -q 
"Resources
| where type has 'microsoft.compute/disks'
| extend diskState = tostring(properties.diskState)
| where managedBy == ''
or diskState == 'Attached'
or diskState == 'Unattached'
| project name, diskState,managedBy,resourceGroup, location, subscriptionId, properties.diskSizeGB, properties.timeCreated"
```

Upon reviewing your code block you submitted:

```
az graph query -q “
Resources 
| where type =~ ‘microsoft.compute/disks’ 
| extend diskState = tostring(properties.diskState) 
| where managedBy == "" or diskState == 'Attached' or diskState == 'Unattached' 
| project name, diskState,managedBy,resourceGroup, location, subscriptionId, diskSize=properties.diskSizeGB, timeCreation=properties.timeCreated
” 
--query ‘
data[].{Disk_Name:name, Disk_State:diskState, Managed_By:managedBy, Resource_Group:resourceGroup, Location:location, Subscription_Id:subscriptionId, Disk_Size:diskSize, Time_of_Creation:timeCreation}
’ 
-o tsv
```

I noticed you have two "query" parameters and you have double quotes within your query. Please convert the double quotes to single quotes and only use one query parameter.

Please review this for more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/resource-graph/concepts/explore-resources